# Options of dropdown created using javascript array is not visible in IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Dropdown options are not visible when first time page is loaded.

In details--

how it works--->
I have created number of dropdown lists. on option change for first dropdown, rest of the dropdown deleting selected option. And on option change of second dropdown rest of the drop down again deleting selected option. same process is going on again on again until the last drop down.

Issue-->
This is working fine in google crome but in IE at the time page is loaded no option is visible in any of the dropdown. once selected an option only after that rest of the option get visibled. this is the issue. i want onload also options in dropdown should be visible but somehow in  IE its not working

Thanks in advance :)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<script>



function addlist1(element1, selected_element) {
    var select1 = document.getElementById(element1);
    var newOpt = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"]; 
    var newopt1 ;
    var newopt2 ;

    if(selected_element == 'mySelect' || selected_element == 'mySelect1' || selected_element == 'mySelect2'
        || selected_element == 'mySelect3'|| selected_element == 'mySelect4' || selected_element == 'mySelect5'){
        var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect');
          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);

     if(selected_element == 'mySelect1' || selected_element == 'mySelect2'|| selected_element == 'mySelect3'
             || selected_element == 'mySelect4' || selected_element == 'mySelect5'){
        var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect1');
          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);

       if(selected_element == 'mySelect2'|| selected_element == 'mySelect3'
             || selected_element == 'mySelect4' || selected_element == 'mySelect5'){   
        var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect2');
          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);

         if(selected_element == 'mySelect3'|| selected_element == 'mySelect4' 
                 || selected_element == 'mySelect5'){
        var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect3');

          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);

          if( selected_element == 'mySelect4'  || selected_element == 'mySelect5'){
           var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect4');

          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);

              if(selected_element == 'mySelect5'){
                var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect5');

          newopt1 = newOpt.slice(0, sel.selectedIndex);
          newopt2 = newOpt.slice(sel.selectedIndex + 1, newOpt.length);
          newOpt = newopt1.concat(newopt2);
            } 
          }
          }
       }
      }
    }


     for(var i = 0; i < newOpt.length; i++) {
         var opt = newOpt[i];
         select1.options[i].value  = opt.valueOf();
         select1.options[i].text = opt.valueOf();
         } 
}


 function createList() {
     alert('onload');
     var select = document.getElementById("mySelect"); 
        var select1 = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
var select2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
var select3 = document.getElementById("mySelect3");
var select4 = document.getElementById("mySelect4");
var select5 = document.getElementById("mySelect5");


     var options = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"]; 
     for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
         var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
            select.appendChild(el);
     }
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
         var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;
           select1.appendChild(el);
     }
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
         var opt = options[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;

select2.appendChild(el);
     }
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;

select3.appendChild(el);
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;

select4.appendChild(el);
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
     var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;

select5.appendChild(el);
 }
 }

 function removelist(element_id) {
        alert('remove');
        var selected_element = element_id.id;
        alert(selected_element);
        var e0 = document.getElementById("mySelect");
        var e1 = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
        var e2 = document.getElementById("mySelect2");
        var e3 = document.getElementById("mySelect3");
        var e4 = document.getElementById("mySelect4");
        var e5 = document.getElementById("mySelect5");

    if(selected_element == 'mySelect'){
        addlist1("mySelect1", selected_element);
        addlist1("mySelect2", selected_element);
        addlist1("mySelect3", selected_element);
        addlist1("mySelect4", selected_element);
        addlist1("mySelect5", selected_element);
        e1.remove(4);
        e2.remove(4);
        e3.remove(4);
        e4.remove(4);
        e5.remove(4);   
        } else if(selected_element == 'mySelect1'){

            addlist1("mySelect2", selected_element);
            addlist1("mySelect3", selected_element);
            addlist1("mySelect4", selected_element);
            addlist1("mySelect5", selected_element);
            e2.remove(4);
            e2.remove(3);
            e3.remove(4);
            e3.remove(3);
            e4.remove(4);
            e4.remove(3);
            e5.remove(4);
            e5.remove(3);

            }  else if(selected_element == 'mySelect2'){

                addlist1("mySelect3", selected_element);
                addlist1("mySelect4", selected_element);
                addlist1("mySelect5", selected_element);
                e3.remove(4);
                e3.remove(3);
                e3.remove(2);
                e4.remove(4);
                e4.remove(3);
                e4.remove(2);
                e5.remove(4);
                e5.remove(3);
                e5.remove(2);

                }  else if(selected_element == 'mySelect3'){

                    addlist1("mySelect4", selected_element);
                    addlist1("mySelect5", selected_element);
                    e4.remove(4);
                    e4.remove(3);
                    e4.remove(2);
                    e4.remove(1);
                    e5.remove(4);
                    e5.remove(3);
                    e5.remove(2);
                    e5.remove(1);


                    }  else if(selected_element == 'mySelect4'){

                        addlist1("mySelect5", selected_element);
                        e5.remove(5);
                        e5.remove(4);
                        e5.remove(3);
                        e5.remove(2);
                        e5.remove(1);

                        }

           }


 </script>
<body onload ="createList()">
<form id="mainForm" action= "" method ="get">
Criteria One:
<select id="mySelect" onchange="removelist(this)">
</select>
<select id="mySelect1" onchange="removelist(this)">
</select>
<select id="mySelect2" onchange="removelist(this)">
</select>
<select id="mySelect3" onchange="removelist(this)">
</select>
<select id="mySelect4" onchange="removelist(this)">
</select>
<select id="mySelect5">
</select>
         </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `<script>` should be in your `<head>`. And why don't you remove unnecessary code to reproduce the problem, so that we can clearly see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried to make your code more maintainable by not using IDs, but the nodes themselves. That way, you don't have to repeat chunks of code for each select. I do however assign them IDs for later processing. I don't know what did it, but it works for me in IE, if you select from left to right:

```js
var selects = [],
    numOfSelects = 6,
    options = ["ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"];
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', createList, false);

function createList() {
    var form = document.getElementById("mainForm");
    for(var i = 0; i < numOfSelects; i++){
        var select = document.createElement('select');
        select.id = "mySelect" + i;
        selects.push(select);
        selects[i].addEventListener('change', removeList, false);
        for (var j = 0, k = options.length; j < k; j++) {
            var el = document.createElement("option");
            el.textContent = el.value = options[j];
            selects[i].appendChild(el);
        }
        form.appendChild(select);
    }
}

function removeList(ev) {
    var el = ev.currentTarget,
        value = el.value;
    for(var i = 0, l = selects.length; i<l; i++){
        if(selects[i].isSameNode(el)){continue;}
        var options = selects[i].childNodes;
        for(var j = 0, k = options.length; j < k; j++){
            if(options[j].value == value){
                selects[i].remove(j);
                j--;k--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="mainForm" action= "" method ="get">
    Criteria One:
</form>
```